# Redirect with htaccess with variable

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I would like to redirect all my php files to without php extension.
Like news.php to news or articles.php to articles. I know about this htacces command:

```
Redirect 301 /news.php /news
```

But I would like to make with variable, something like this but does not work:

```
Redirect 301 ^(.*)$ /$1.php
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the rewrite module for this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule 301 ^(.*)\.php$ $1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need a redirect rule to remove `.php` extension and a rewrite rule to add `.php` extension silently. Try these 2 rules in your root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

# To externally redirect /dir/file.php to /dir/file
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R,L]

# To internally redirect /dir/file to /dir/file.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```